# Copy the symlink as a symlink, _and_ its referant

Tags: rsync, symlink

Let's say I have on host A:

/foo/afile -> /bar/afile

Now on host B, the result of:

rsync -l hostA:/foo/afile /foo

is a broken symlink in `/foo/afile`, and the result of:

rsync -L hostA:/foo/afile /foo

is a regular file `/foo/afile`.

What's a good way to run rsync from host B, ending up with `/foo/afile -> /bar/afile` on host B?  Can it be made to work even if host B has no advance knowledge of the path `/bar`?

Answer (score 1):

As described in [this Mac OS X Hint](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050419230722397&ei=PxgHU8GhDqHX4AT9xID4Cg&usg=AFQjCNGj85mpx9ZgysTC-kGdREtX8dl0Zg&sig2=Oxc4W8DK3F80u53a0rBNwg&bvm=bv.61725948,d.bGE) you could make the symlink relative to the current path. Something like

```
cd /foo
ln -s ../bar/afile ./afile
```